# How to locally install React App 5.0.0 when create-react-app does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an error in making a **new React App**, the command { **npx create-react-app my-app** } does not work. It says { **You are running create-react-app "4.0.3", which is behind the latest release 5.0.0**   }. I did run the command to uninstall any global installation of React app and it still not works.
have also tried updating the node to the latest version and I am using **Node v16.13.2**. I have also **[installed react-scripts@5.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlraw.png)** but it's not at all working
Please help me out, as of now I am unable to make any react app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGoP4.png)

Comment: I had the same problem when running in vscode terminal. Running on cmd worked for me.